# Working with single file rust using rust-analyzer

Tags: vim, rust, rust-cargo, language-server-protocol, coc.nvim

I'm trying to make rust-analyzer (with Neovim) work with a single Rust file.
I know that using Cargo should be the default, but I'm trying to solve problems like the ones from [project euler](http://projecteuler.net/), where making a project for each problem seems like an overkill.
Furthermore, I solve problems in various languages, so I want to make each code self-contained.

However, with [coc-rust-analyzer](https://github.com/fannheyward/coc-rust-analyzer), it says:

```
[coc.nvim] rust-analyzer failed to discover workspace, no Cargo.toml found, dirs searched: /Users/jay/some-dir
```

I just want to run rust-analyzer with this file only. What should I do?

—————

Update:
I'm just starting to use Rust, and I used Python, OCaml, C++ for previous problems. I used `rustc` for a simple problem.

Languages like OCaml provides a (verbose) solution using 
`ocamlfind` & `ocamlopt`, and to use [merlin](https://github.com/ocaml/merlin) which is a tool for vim and emacs, I only need a top level `.merlin` file like

```
PKG core stdio ppx_deriving.std ppx_variants_conv
```

that lists all the packages I need to use.
I could have used [dune](https://github.com/ocaml/dune), which is kind of like the build system part of cargo.

I found that `rustc` can link external crates, e.g. `rustc executable.rs --extern rary=library.rlib && ./executable`. I admit this may be more complex than a Cargo based solution, but still makes me wonder if rust-analyzer can only work with Cargo based projects.

Comment: If you aren't using Cargo, how are you building and running your code? How are you building and linking dependencies like `rand` and `num`, which you will no doubt need for Project Euler? It looks like you are making your life unnecessarily difficult, for no clear benefit. Running `cargo new` for each problem doesn't seem to be _that_ much overhead. Alternatively, you can also have many main programs in `src/bin`.

Comment: I organize my rust leetcode solutions in one single project in different modules with tests. That seems to be solving it for me.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I didn't know Rust didn't have a built-in solution for rands. Thank you.

Comment: @Kuznero I'll take a look at this workaround, thank you

Comment: I still recommend using a single package with multiple main programs in `src/bin`. You can compile them separately with `cargo build --bin <name>` for the file `src/bin/<name>.rs`, and you can add common library code in `src/lib.rs`, which you can use in any of the binaries.

Comment: If you really want to use single-file Rust code, there is rust-script: https://rust-script.org/. But again, go with @SvenMarnach and make it one project with multiple bin targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rust-analyzer can work for standalone/single rust file, https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/pull/8955, coc-rust-analyzer supports this too.

Comment: yes but how do i configure rust analyzer for single file ? being in sublime text for example